# Programatically check free shipping is active or not in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, free-shipping

How can I programatically check free shipping is active or not in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check free shipping is Enabled from admin, you can use below code

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/freeshipping/active', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```